# How to pass properties to WPF Style

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to write a reusable Template for a WPF ItemContainerStyle.

This Template changes the way the TabControl's Item looks.
This template is meant to be used in several places in the application.

In each place it is used I want to be able to pass different parameters to it.
For example: to change the Margin of the Border of the Item:

```
    <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">

                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0"/>

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Border x:Name="Bd" Width="80"  
                                  Background="Gray" 
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" 
                                        ContentSource="Header" />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
...
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
```

In the place where the style is used I Would like to Write something like:

```
ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1 Margin='5,0'}"
```

or

```
<TabControl Margin="78,51,167,90" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}"
            ItemContainerStyle.Margin="5,0">
```

The motivation is to use this template in different places with different Margins.
Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've found a way to do this with dave's help.

The Solution is to create a derived template and set the properties in it.
This way the original template can be reused.

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemStyle1}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,0"></Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

And set the TabControl's ItemContainerStyle to the derived style:

```
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle2}">
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with attached properties. I wrote a blog post explaining how to do it:

http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/10/01/wpf-creating-parameterized-styles-with-attached-properties/

Another option is to use `DynamicResource`, and redefine the resource in derived styles

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Your first answer is clear and elegant, However I wanted a way to do this without writing any additional C# code. My answer above does this, but again - writing a small static class isn't a big deal and it might be even more elegant. Thank you.

Comment: By the way - My answer (above) uses static properties.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to change some parameters deep in the applied template (so I couldn't use just a setter).
And I didn't want to code some classes that traverse the visual tree or register an attached property to do the changes.

However, it is possible to define resources within the base style and override these values in the derived definitions. So, with the original example this would look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="AbsTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <!-- Override these default values in derived style definitions -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <s:Double x:Key="GridBorderMargin">10</s:Double>
        <Color x:Key="GridBorderColor">Grey</Color>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd"
                            Width="80"
                            Background="{DynamicResouces GridBorderColor}"
                            Margin="{DynamicResouces GridBorderMargin}"
                            >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" 
                            ContentSource="Header" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BigMarginTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AbsTabItemStyle}">
    <!-- Set different values in this derived style definition -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <s:Double x:Key="GridBorderMargin">20</s:Double>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="RedTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource AbsTabItemStyle}">
    <!-- Set different values in this derived style definition -->
    <Style.Resources>
        <c:Color x:Key="GridBorderColor">Red</Color>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of solving it is by adding a Margin property to the objects/ViewModels you want to display and (data)bind to that value in the template.

As far as I know there is no support of parameterized styles/templates.